# unity3d - AI terrain detection

Tags: unity, ai

My goal is to have my animals walk around within a certain range. Everything works except for when it comes to the y axis. I can choose a position for it to walk and it will go there but I have no way of telling the height of the terrain at the selected point, or at the points all along the way. Im wondering how I can have my npc's always walk on the ground rather than walking through the ground.

My code is here if it helps, but my problem is pretty straight forward.

```
    if(timer == 0) {
        //Look at target
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (walkToPosition - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Vector3.Distance (walkToPosition, myTransform.position) > 1) {
            //Move towards target
            myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            anim.CrossFade("walk");
        } else {
            walkToPosition.x = Random.Range(initialSpawn.x - walkDistance, initialSpawn.x + walkDistance);
            walkToPosition.z = Random.Range(initialSpawn.z - walkDistance, initialSpawn.z + walkDistance);
            timer = walkCooldown;
            anim.CrossFade("idle");
        }
        Debug.Log (walkToPosition);
    }
```

EDIT:

I am doing this project in Unity3d. I do not need to know how to render this, all I am looking for is some kind of function or something that I can use to tell the character to walk along the ground rather than walking through it.

At the moment when I set a new walk to position, the Y coord is 0, which means the character is going to forcibly go to the 0 axis without even considering the terrain.

Comment: How is your terrain drawn? What is it made of? How are the vertices originally created? Are you already using spatial data structures?

Comment: Idk its unity theres a Terrain gameObject

Comment: You will need to interpolate between the nearest vertices to calculate a Y, per (X,Z). The method I posted "renders" the calculation on the GPU, rather than chugging it on the CPU.

Comment: Ohh okay, it just looked like a lot more than what I need :P I understand I need to interpolate and find the point of Y, but in Unity there has to be a way to access a Y position of the Terrain object based on X and Z, I was just wondering if anyone here has done it before.

Comment: Quick Google got me to TerrainData.GetHeight(x,y). I suspect that it samples from the heightmap, rather than doing CPU-bound interpolation. Are you using the heightmap?

Comment: That should work thank you very much, was late last night musta missed it!